# Apache не отображает ошибки в браузере

Tags: php, linux, apache, lamp

Установил LAMP. Если кто не знает - Linux + Apache + MySQL + PHP.
Если в скрипте PHP сделать ошибку, то браузер выдаст:

"Страница недоступна

Сайт mysite.com пока не может обработать этот запрос.

HTTP ERROR 500"

На Windows + Denwer при ошибке, браузер отображал её. Та и сайт на хостинге тоже отображает.
Как заставить LAMP делать тоже самое?

Comment: Скриншот и скриншот кода, если можно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут может быть два варианта:

**В PHP отключён вывод ошибок**

Поищите в конфигах `php.ini` и в `.htaccess` и в `httpd.conf` директивы:

`error_reporting=E_ALL` `display_errors=On`

Я указал нужные вам значения. У вас они могут отличаться.

Так же вы можете установить их из скрипта:

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

**Так же это может быть сам Apache** некорректно настроен. Попробуйте убрать файлы .htaccess из директории хоста.

Comment: когда добавил эти строки в скрипт, то все заработало. Но в php.ini я их не нашел. У меня PHP 7.0

Comment: Все файлы просмотрели?

Comment: .htaccess - вовсе нет в корне сайта. Я его не создавал. А "httpd.conf" я даже не знаю, что это.

Comment: получилось. Спасибо большое. Просто надо было открывать нормальным редактором php.ini.

Comment: мне помогла команда sudo notepadqq /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

Comment: действительно было display_errors=Off